# Detect clicked particle in particle system

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have particles, which are a THREE.Geometry, that have 50 particles pushed to particles.vertices when I setup my scene. I then create a THREE.ParticleSystem with particles. When I mousedown on the document the following function fires:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(particles);

    console.log(intersects); // outputs empty array?
}
```

However, the intersects always returns an empty array. Am I missing something? How do I detect which particle is clicked on mousedown? I'm doing this in WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Ray doesn't support ParticleSystem now. You can find several ideas on how to solve this problem [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1264). In this [pull request](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/2061) you can find working example of how it can be done, but that soultion is based on particles size thresholds, so its not perfect, but in simple case it should be ok.

Comment: Bummer, those solutions are using different revisions of Three.js and seem very specific to the demo. I was hoping for a solution using the current master version.

Comment: yep, i've tried just to give you a direction. In such situation I've written my own intersection function, but it is too specific to post it here.